# .NET Generics Type Constraint Inequality

Tags: .net, type-systems, generic-constraints

I'm trying to implement two generic interfaces. It makes sense that `ITwoWayMapper<T,U>` would implement both `IOneWayMapper<T,U>` and `IOneWayMapper<U,T>`. So if I try to do just that:

```
public interface IOneWayMapper<T, U>
{
    U Map(T source);
}

public interface ITwoWayMapper<T, U> :
    IOneWayMapper<T, U>,
    IOneWayMapper<U, T>
{
    TTwo Map(TOne source);
    TOne Map(TTwo source);
}
```

I get the error `Interface ITwoWayMapper<T,U> cannot implement both IOneWayMapper<T,U> and IOneWayMapper<U,T> because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions`. So I think, well okay it makes sense that this is ambiguous because it couldn't tell which interface is being satisfied.

So this leads to my question: Is it possible to use type constraints to say something like this?:

```
public interface ITwoWayMapper<T, U> :
    IOneWayMapper<T, U>,
    IOneWayMapper<U, T>
    where T: !U
{
    TTwo Map(TOne source);
    TOne Map(TTwo source);
}
```

Comment: No, you can't make up your own syntax.  Just add the T Map(U source) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 13.4.2 of the C# Specification

> If any possible constructed type created from C would, after type arguments are substituted into L, cause two interfaces in L to be identical, then the declaration of C is invalid. **Constraint declarations are not considered when determining all possible constructed types.**

So the answer is: no. Even if there was a type constraint such as `T : !U`, it would be ignored and you'd still bump into the same collision.

Comment: I suppose I should just delegate this responsibility to the concrete class then and have it implement `IOneWayMapper<ConcreteType1, ConcreteType2>` and `IOneWayMapper<ConcreteType2, ConcreteType1>`. Thanks for the help. For anyone else, the link to that spec is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664592(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @TroyP. Sounds like a reasonable solution :)